# How can I solve the NJS error: 012, what is the correct way to add the date?

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I want to execute a stored procedure that has the following structure:

`PROCEDURE Proc_Genctabalcons(Idtfechai DATE, Idtfechaf DATE, Inucliente NUMBER, Inunodo NUMBER, Inupunto NUMBER, Isbuser VARCHAR2, Isbterm VARCHAR2, Isbopc VARCHAR2, Onuerror OUT INTEGER, Osberror OUT VARCHAR2);`

I want to execute the procedure from nodejs but when passing the parameters it gives me the following error:

```js
sql = `BEGIN
        pk_emgnomi.Proc_Genctabalcons(:Idtfechai, :Idtfechaf, :Inucliente,
        :Inunodo, :Inupunto, :Isbuser, :Isbterm, :Isbopc, :Onuerror, :Osberror);
     END;
`;
    params = {
    Idtfechai: {value:  new Date('24/07/2019'), type : oracledb.DATE} ,
    Idtfechaf: {value: new Date('24/07/2019'), type: oracledb.DATE},
    Inucliente: -1 ,
    Inunodo: -1,
    Inupunto: -1,
    Isbuser: "MIGRACION",
    Isbterm: "MIGRACION",
    Isbopc: "MIGRACION",
    Onuerror: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT},
    Onuerror: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT},

};
result = await connection.execute(sql, params);
```

when executing I have the following error:

**Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2**

I think this error is due to the dates, but I don't know how to give it a correct format, some help?

Comment: This was answered in the duplicate post: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1127